# amChart bar color

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I am tring to change my column color dynamically. My data is an array of objects `[{name:"jan", value:3}]`. If the value is below 2 set the column color to green, if it is above 2 set it to orange etc. I need to loop through cols and check the value and then set the apropriate fill value.

```
am5.ready(function() {
    // Create root element
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/getting-started/#Root_element
    var root = am5.Root.new("chartdiv");
    
    // Set themes
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/themes/
    root.setThemes([
      am5themes_Animated.new(root)
    ]);
    
    
    // Create chart
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/
    var chart = root.container.children.push(am5xy.XYChart.new(root, {
      panX: true,
      panY: true,
      wheelX: "panX",
      wheelY: "zoomX",
      pinchZoomX:true
    }));
    
    // Add cursor
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/cursor/
    var cursor = chart.set("cursor", am5xy.XYCursor.new(root, {}));
    cursor.lineY.set("visible", false);
    
    
    // Create axes
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/axes/
    var xRenderer = am5xy.AxisRendererX.new(root, { minGridDistance: 30 });
    xRenderer.labels.template.setAll({
      rotation: -90,
      centerY: am5.p50,
      centerX: am5.p100,
      paddingRight: 15
    });
    
    var xAxis = chart.xAxes.push(am5xy.CategoryAxis.new(root, {
      maxDeviation: 0.3,
      categoryField: "name",
      renderer: xRenderer,
      tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {})
    }));
    
    var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
      maxDeviation: 0.3,
      renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {})
    }));
    
    
    // Create series
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/charts/xy-chart/series/
    var series = chart.series.push(am5xy.ColumnSeries.new(root, {
      name: "Series 1",
      xAxis: xAxis,
      yAxis: yAxis,
      valueYField: "value",
      sequencedInterpolation: true,
      categoryXField: "name",
      tooltip: am5.Tooltip.new(root, {
        labelText:"{valueY}"
      })
    }));
    
    series.columns.template.setAll({ cornerRadiusTL: 5, cornerRadiusTR: 5});
    
    
    var myChart = document.getElementById('chartdiv');
    var data = JSON.parse( myChart.dataset.chartdata )
    
    xAxis.data.setAll(data);
    series.data.setAll(data);
    
    data.forEach((col) => {
        if(col.value >= 0 && col.value < 2.5){
            console.log(col , ': green')
        }
        if(col.value >= 2.5 && col.value < 5){
            console.log(col , ': orange')
        }
        if(col.value >= 5){
            console.log(col , ': red')
        }
    })
    

    // Make stuff animate on load
    // https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/animations/
    series.appear(1000);
    chart.appear(1000, 100);

}); // end am5.ready()
```